# Retrieving images from Database into ArrayList and Displaying it one by one from ArrayList in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

using following code i store images into ArrayList.

```
    public ArrayList getImagesToArray(string qry)
    {

        ArrayList arr;
        if (myConn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            myConn.Open();
        if (myDR != null)
            myDR.Close();
        myComm = new SqlCommand(qry, myConn);

        using (myComm)
        {
            arr = new ArrayList();
            myDR = myComm.ExecuteReader();
            while (myDR.Read())
            {
                arr.Add((byte[])myDR[0]);
            }
            return arr;
        }     
    }
```

**Now i retreive images to an ArrayList using Following Code**

```
ArrayList arrImgs_Main = Q.getImagesToArray("Select FieldImg from InfoTagQA I INNER JOIN PensionScannedDocs P on p.ScanImageID=i.ScanImageID Where P.PersonalNumber='" + hid_PersonalNo.Value + "'");
```

**Now I display image one by one from arrayList to ImageUrl by clicking Next and Previous button**

```
protected void lnk_BackImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    try
    {      
        if (arrImgs_Main.Count > 0)
        {        
            if (i > 0)
            {
                i--;
                img_mainImage.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])arrImgs_Main[i]);
                lab_TotalRecords.Text = "(" + (i + 1) + "/" + arrImgs_Main.Count + ")";
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    lnk_ForwardImage.Visible = true;
                    lnk_BackImage.Visible = false;
                }
            }         
        }   
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
        ShowErrorMsg(ee.Message);
    }   
}
```

**All above code works fine and quick on my local machine, but after deployment on server , it take much time in displaying image one by one from array.
Am i doing doing right in above code or going on wrong way. Please guide me **

Comment: Nobody uses an ArrayList anymore. We use the [generic List<T> class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, it appears you're using your SqlConnection incorrectly. It implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). You shouldn't store it as a field in your class.

Comment: tell me the correct way

Comment: I gave you links that explain it.

Comment: Your answer is not particular to my question, i have adopted methods as you defined, The loading of image byte to Generic List or ArrayList dont take time, the time only take is displaying image to image URL only.

Comment: I am not telling you how to solve your question. I am pointing out serious flaws in your code that you need to fix.